# How to check whether given xml is valid or invalid in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-validation

I wanted to do validation of xml in objective c. Is there any provision or way in objective c to check whether the given xml is valid or not ?

Comment: @Safecase : But where is Objective-c involved here.

Comment: ya i want to check it in a objective c program

Comment: Would you mind to tell what kind of XML parser you use? TBXML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NSXMLDocument for this:

```
 NSError *err;
 NSXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:furl            options:(NSXMLDocumentValidate | NSXMLNodePreserveAll)
                                                error:&err];

 BOOL vaildXML = [xmlDoc validateAndReturnError:&err];
 NSLog(@"Error : %@",[err description]);
```

For ios use **NSXMLParser**

It will not crash, if **NSXMLParser** finds an error, it will let you know through its delegate, either by invoking **parser:validationErrorOccurred:** or **– parser:parseErrorOccurred:**. You can use the **- (NSError *)parserError** in NSXMLParser to determine the error wich caused the parsing to terminate.

Comment: For using NSXMLDocument which header i have to import

Comment: But the documention says NSXML parser doesn't invoke this method (validationErrorOccured).how can i validate xml string in ios.plz help     Refer link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://knol2share.blogspot.ro/2009/05/validate-xml-against-xsd-in-c.html) is a method  , and the [library](http://cmar.me/2011/04/20/adding-libxml2-to-an-xcode-4-project/).

You can also validate XML using the following unix command:

```
xmllint --noout --schema test.xsd test.xml
```

EDIT:

Try the following code:

```
NSXMLDocument *doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:urlData options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* tempArray = [doc nodesForXPath:@"path/to/the/xml" error:&error];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: He may need a schema though to validate it. libxml2 is a good option. However if one sticks to NSXMLParser, a malformed xml returns nil when one tries to initialise it. +1 nevertheless for validation against a schema.